# Check if a value is within a numrange in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, range-types, operator

In PostgreSQL 16, I need to check if a value is within a `numrange` stored in a table.
I found the following example with an `int4range`

```
SELECT 14 <@ (SELECT my_range
FROM my_table
WHERE id = 1);
```

But when I tried it with my `numrange`, I got

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer <@ numrange  
LINE 1: SELECT 14 <@ (SELECT my_range  
                  ^  
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm not sure what I need to cast. How should I proceed?

Comment: Maybe you don't need `numrange` to begin with, and `int4range` is good enough? Then the problem goes away. But still read my answer for fine print.

Comment: Based on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-EXAMPLES I guess I need `numrange` because my range could be `(11.1, 22.2)` and not always with integer bounds.

Comment: You do need `numrange` then.

Answer (score 3):

#### TLDR

Cast to `numeric`:

```
SELECT numeric '14' <@ '[1,2]'::numrange;  -- works
```

#### Why?

There is an implicit cast from `integer` to `numeric`. That is not the problem.

The problem is that the numeric constant `14` (without single-quotes) initially resolves to type `integer`, the operator you want is the generic [**`anyelement <@ anyrange`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE), and [operator type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html#id-1.5.9.7.4) does not arrive there.

`anyelement` and `anyrange` are [pseudo types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html), more specifically, [**polymorphic types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC). The operator to be used is determined by actual input types. You must be specific about the input, Postgres cannot assume too much. Furthermore, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC)

> [...] if there are positions declared `anyrange` and others declared `anyelement` or `anyarray`, the actual range type in the `anyrange` positions must be a range whose subtype is the same type appearing in the `anyelement` positions and the same as the element type of the `anyarray` positions.

In short, if one is given, the other must match exactly.

**This expression works:**

```
SELECT 14. <@ '[1,2]'::numrange;  -- works, a bit obfuscated
```

Because `14.` is [**numeric constant**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html##SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC) (a.k.a. "numeric literal") that is initially presumed to be type `numeric`. (The word "numeric" in "numeric constant" does not predetermine the type to be `numeric`, mind you. Same word, two distinct meanings.) Numeric literals resolve to `integer`, `bigint` or `numeric`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html##SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC)

> A numeric constant that contains neither a decimal point nor an
> exponent is initially presumed to be type `integer` if its value fits
> in type integer (32 bits); otherwise it is presumed to be type
> `bigint` if its value fits in type bigint (64 bits); otherwise it is
> taken to be type `numeric`. **Constants that contain decimal points
> and/or exponents are always initially presumed to be type `numeric`.**

**Bold** emphasis mine.

There are no "floating point literals" in Postgres, strictly speaking. And trying an explicit floating point (`float` = `float8` = `double precision`) fails also:

```
SELECT float '14' <@ '[1,2]'::numrange;  -- fails!
```

In simple cases, you could still use `'14'` (with single-quotes) as [**string constant**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) (a.k.a. "string literal") without explicit cast. Then, operator type resolution would eventually coerce that to the matching type `numeric`.

```
SELECT '14' <@ '[1,2]'::numrange;  -- fails in this case!
```

**However**, it fails in this particular case, because there is another operator **`anyrange <@ anyrange`** in the system, which binds first. The left type is the same as the right, and that binds earlier. So the literal is presumed to be type `numrange`, and trying to cast it produces this error:

> ERROR:  Missing left parenthesis or bracket.malformed range literal: "14"

If you'd drop the operator **`anyrange <@ anyrange`**, the expression would still fail because there is a third operator **`'anymultirange' <@ anyrange`**, and the ambiguity would result in:

> ERROR:  operator is not unique: numrange @> unknown

It would work after dropping that, too. (I verified. But, obviously, don't do that!)

So, unless you register an operator for `numeric <@ numrange`, or even `integer <@ numrange` (don't!), the remaining solution is an explicit cast. No ambiguity left, the **gold standard**. (Or work with a variable / parameter typed `numeric` to begin with.):

```
SELECT numeric '14' <@ '[1,2]'::numrange;  -- works
SELECT '14'::numeric <@ '[1,2]'::numrange;  -- works
```

Well, you *could* cast `numrange` to `int4range`. There is no direct cast registered, you could use `text` as stepping stone:

```
SELECT 14 <@ '[1,2]'::numrange::text::int4range;  -- works, but ugly
```

Of course, all range boundaries have to be valid for `int4` (then why use `numrange` to begin with?), and it's a very expensive, non-sargable expression. So, don't, unless circumstances force your hand.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what I need to cast

Since you cannot cast `numrange` to `int4range`, obviously the only candidate for casting is the literal. You can do it explicitly:

```
select 14::numeric <@ (select my_range from ranges where id = 1)
```

or use a numeric literal that can be implicitly cast to a `numeric`:

```
select 14. <@ (select my_range from ranges where id = 1)
```

Generally though you should make all your cast explicit.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/skOHke1k).